# why can't I copy and paste

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this code in js to validate my text in an html input field.  It works great except that I can't copy/paste anything into the textbox.  How can I modify this to allow copy/pasting while not losing the validation functionality?  Or is there a better way to validate a textbox?

```
function checkText(e)
{       
    var ok = /[a-z A-Z]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    if (!ok)
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: How is this function linked to the input element?  `onchange`?  or one of the key events?

Comment: When you paste, there's no `e.charCode`. That only exists in keyboard events.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44558661

Comment: I am calling this with "onkeypress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been mentioned in the comments, the paste event does not have the charcode property. You can try the following to handle both events:

```
function checkText(e)
{       
   var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) || (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text')
   var ok = /[a-z A-Z]/.test(str);
   if (!ok)
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

So you handle both the keyboard and the paste events. The paste event will have to be only one char though.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```js
function checkInput(elem){
  let newValue = elem.value.split("").filter(chr => /[a-z A-Z]/.test(chr)).join("")
  elem.value = newValue;
}
```

```html
<input onInput="checkInput(this);">
```

Comment: @user2236794 so please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out my problem was that somewhere in my code, there was code like this:

```
document.body.onpaste = (e) => { 
   e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

`preventDefault()` prevents normal paste operations.

i rewrote this line to only prevent default on a specific element that needed it (instead of the entire body), and then i was able to paste into my textboxes again